# How to select min date group by name with repeated ids

Tags: mysql

I have a table with `id`, `name`, `date` and `value`

My table is:

```
id  name   date         value 
---|------|------------|-------------
1  | john | 01/03/2017 | 399 
1  | john | 02/03/2017 | 244
1  | paul | 01/03/2017 | 555
1  | paul | 02/03/2017 | 313
2  | john | 03/04/2017 | 433
2  | john | 04/04/2017 | 651
2  | paul | 05/04/2017 | 657
2  | paul | 06/04/2017 | 131
3  | john | 03/05/2017 | 656
3  | john | 24/05/2017 | 543
3  | paul | 01/05/2017 | 114
3  | paul | 02/05/2017 | 966
```

I need to select min date group by name and his value.

I need to get this:

```
id  name   date         value 
---|------|------------|-------------
1  | john | 01/03/2017 | 399     
1  | paul | 01/03/2017 | 555
2  | john | 03/04/2017 | 433
2  | paul | 05/04/2017 | 657
3  | john | 03/05/2017 | 656
3  | paul | 01/05/2017 | 114
```

I have tried this mysql query:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    mytable a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  name, MIN(date) mindate
            FROM    mytable 
            GROUP   BY name
        ) b ON a.name = b.name
                AND a.date= b.mindate
                ORDER BY a.id
```

Comment: What is type of your date column?

Comment: The type of date datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    mytable a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  id, name, MIN(date) mindate
            FROM    mytable 
            GROUP   BY id, name
        ) b ON a.id = b.id
                AND a.name = b.name
                AND a.date= b.mindate
                ORDER BY a.id
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b2743/1)

Because the expected result has each name with minimum date in the given id.

Also, this will produce correct results only if there is only one row with minimum value per id and name.

Comment: Yes works! but I prefer @flo option because I get the same results and execution time is 0.0004sg vs 0.70sg

Comment: @kurtko Sure. It's fast and *WRONG*

Comment: Why? I get the same results with two queries.

Comment: It's most definitely **not** producing the same result. My query result is 6 rows whereas the other answer produces 10 rows for the given data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select id, name, min(date), value
from mytable
group by id, name, value
```

Comment: Very simple and it seems to work, but I need to remove group by value. This code works for me:
Select *, min(date)
from mytable
group by id, name

Comment: GROUP BY *value* seems highly implausible

Answer (score -1):

Whats the datatype of that field, MySql friendly date are in format 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'. I guess that column have datatype varchar or text. First convert that string to date STR_TO_DATE(t.datestring, '%d/%m/%Y'), than select minimum from that and than format it to your required format. Query would be:

```
select t.id,t.name,DATE_FORMAT(MIN(STR_TO_DATE(t.date,'%d/%m/%Y')), '%d/%m/%Y') as date,t.value
from myTable t group by t.id,t.name
```

Comment: The point was addressed in comments well before you posted your reply. In consequence, this answer contributes nothing to the discussion. Indeed, I'd go further and suggest that the entire proposal is counter-productive. If data is stored poorly, then the solution is to fix how that data is stored.

Comment: @Strawberry which comment has explained about casting string to date selecting the minimum and back to string in required format?